# Agenda jobs go to locked state and never run

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-cron, agenda

I'm using Agenda for job processing. I'm facing an issue with the locking mechanism. I don't know how it works.

If I define a job that is going to run at 12 AM then at 12 AM lockedAt updated with the current time and the job does not run.

I'm using PM2 for the production process manager.

I have initialized agenda like this:

```
let agenda = new Agenda({ db: { address: config.getDbConnectionString() }});
```